# Find the closest value (equal or greater) in a range in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a range with a list of values (depths). I'd like to be able to select the row where the depth matches a value in a cell I provide. If no value matches, the greater value should be selected.

Here's the range.

[image]

The solution I found, is to have a temporary area where I revert the order of the range, then I use `MATCH` to take advantage of the `-1` sort parameter.

Last but not least, I use `INDIRECT` to extract the value of a cell in the same row, but a different column.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),INDIRECT("SAC!F"&(MATCH(A2, SAC!$E$1:$E$23, -1))),)
```

[image]

Is there a better way to achieve this result?

Examples:

- If the cell has value 6 (exact match), I'd like to get 1.6 (same row)
- If the cell has value 10 (no match), I'd like to get 2.2 (round to 12, then get the factor)

Comment: No. It's just an example, the factor must be taken from the row, not calculated with an expression. In fact, the rule you provided would not work for feet.

Comment: As I said, the value for B cannot be pre-determined from A, take it as a requirement.

Comment: What does the "SAC!` part mean? Is that a reference to a different sheet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two options to try:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),INDEX(SORT(SAC!F:F,SAC!E:E,0),MATCH(A2,SORT(SAC!E:E,SAC!E:E,0),-1)),)`

`=QUERY(SAC!E:F,"select F where E >= "&A2&" order by E limit 1",0)`

---

It's a shame that VLOOKUP doesn't accept the -1 sort parameter, otherwise this would work:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),VLOOKUP(A2,SORT(SAC!E:F,1,0),2,-1),)`

Comment: `QUERY` worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I just had a similar problem and solved it nicely with the MINIFS function:

```
=MINIFS(SAC!E$2:E$23, SAC!A$2:A$23, ">=" & A2)
```

In short:

select the minimum value from the factor column, where the value in the depth column is equal to or greater than the given value.

Comment: This is awesome. I needed MAXIFS in my case, but this was a perfect way to handle the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
=IFERROR(index(B:B,match(F4,A:A,0)),index(B5:B100,match(F4,A4:A99)))
```

where F4 contains the `6`/`10` value.

Comment: 6 and 10 are just examples, the formula should work for any value in the depth range, not just for 6/10.

Comment: No, it does not. Apart that the fields where completely wrong, I was able to reuse `INDEX` to simplify the formula into `=IF(ISNUMBER(A4),INDEX(SAC!E:F,(MATCH(A4, SAC!E:E, -1)), 2),)`, but it still doesn't fix the problem of the order. If I sort with `0` and I don't use the field sorted in reverse range, it does not select the right value.