# Google Sheets - Highlight nearest value - Swimming Times

Tags: google-sheets

I'm banging my head against a wall trying to find a way to highlight a swimming time compared to results from past swim meets.

- Column A is my swimmers time
- Column B is the event
- Column D is the time for a few places within that event
- Column E-W is the time result for that place of that event per college conference (row 1 = conference)

**Goal - Highlight the nearest place my swimmers time would put them in each conference.**

Example - My swimmers 50 Free time of 24.85 would put them closest to 32nd place in the BIG12, 1st place in the SAAC and 9th place in the PCSC.

A copy of my data is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KNpf8Yq15q7ezrXnQMIB6V866K7GAFMLTkmOjBtpf2U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the closest value (equal or greater) in a range in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69743/find-the-closest-value-equal-or-greater-in-a-range-in-google-spreadsheets)

Comment: I don't think so, but thank you. I believe some conditional formatting is going to be required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula :

`=if(isna(query({$A$2:$B$64,indirect(address(2,vlookup(L$1,$R:$S,2,false ),1,1)&":"&address(counta($B:$B),vlookup(L$1,$R:$S,2,false ),1,1))}, "Select Col1 where Col2 = '"&$K2&"' and Col3 <= '"&$J2&"' order by Col3  desc limit 1 ",)),1,query({$A$2:$B$64,indirect(address(2,vlookup(L$1,$R:$S,2,false ),1,1)&":"&address(counta($B:$B),vlookup(L$1,$R:$S,2,false ),1,1))}, "Select Col1 where Col2 starts with '"&$K2&"' and Col3 <= '"&$J2&"' order by Col3  desc limit 1 ",))`

Refer the screenshot below: copy the formula into cell L2, and copy it across to column P, and drag down for as many swimmer's times as are needed.

**LOGIC**

- **Conference Names/Columns Table**

  - Columns S and T display the names of the conferences and the column number in which the conference results are found
  - `=transpose(C1:G1)` = Column names
  - `=arrayformula(row(B2:B6)+1)` = Column number of the relevant conference results (BIG12=C=3, SAAC=D=4, etc)
  - The column numbers are used to create dynamic ranges for the query
- **Query Range**

  - `$A$2:$B$64` = Place and Event
  - `indirect(address(2,vlookup(L$1,$R:$S,2,false ),1,1)&":"&address(counta($B:$B),vlookup(L$1,$R:$S,2,false ),1,1))` = relevant Conference Times

    - `INDIRECT()` returns a range contained in a string
    - `ADDRESS()` returns a cell reference as a string; in this case two cells are joined by a colon `&":"&` to create a range
    - `address(2,vlookup(L$1,$R:$S,2,false ),1,1)&":"&address(counta($B:$B),vlookup(L$1,$R:$S,2,false ),1,1)` creates a dynamic range
    - part1= returns the starting cell of the relevant conference results by taking the conference name in L1:P1 and referencing the Conference Names/Columns Table to yield the column number.
    - part2= returns the ending cell of the relevant conference results by counting the number of rows in the Events column (B); the column number is the same as part1.
- **Query Criteria**

  - `Select Col1 where Col2 = '"&$K2&"' and Col3 <= '"&$J2&"' order by Col3  desc limit 1`
  - Col1 = Place (Column A)
  - `where Col2 = '"&$K2&"' and Col3 <= '"&$J2&"'` combines matching the Conference Event to the swimmer's event (in Cell K2) AND the the conference time is less than or equal to the swimmer's time (in Cell J2).
- **IF(ISNA()...**

  - Where the swimmer's time is less than a Conference first place time (such as 23.91 compared to SAAC first place of 24.46), the query returns #N/A. `IF(ISNA()` is used to assign a first place result in those cases.

---

**Sample data**

[image: screenshot]

Note: MVCC 50FREE last place time was an error; must be greater than other times in the race.